# sql delete cascade not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, cascade, cascading-deletes

I have a Microsoft SQL Database with 2 tables: dog and cat.

"dog" table has a primary key column called "food", which is related to a column called "food" as well in the "cat" table, which acts as the foreign key.

The relationship between the tables has an "on delete cascade" rule set, so when I delete a row from "dog" table, the relveant rows from "cat" table should be deleted as well.

But the rows in "cat" table do net get deleted, they stay. I use the Microsoft SQL Database manager to delete the row in "dog" table.

Any idea why this happens? do I need to use a special delete sql command to delete a row in this manner?

//edit

the script for the tables is:

```
USE [VELES]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Periods]    Script Date: 01/18/2011 14:52:19 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Periods](
    [PeriodID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [PeriodName] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Hebrew_CS_AS NULL,
    [PeriodStartDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [PeriodEndDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Periods] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PeriodID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


USE [VELES]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Exams]    Script Date: 01/18/2011 14:55:37 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Exams](
    [ExamID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ExamUserID] [char](7) COLLATE Hebrew_CS_AS NOT NULL,
    [ExamBase] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [ExamUserTimesAccessed] [tinyint] NULL,
    [ExamMaxTimesToOpen] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [ExamUserLastTimeOpened] [datetime] NULL,
    [ExamUserLastTimeFinished] [datetime] NULL,
    [ExamTimeToFinish] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ExamPassGrade] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ExamPeriod] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ExamUserRank] [tinyint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Exams] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ExamID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
USE [VELES]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Exams]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Exams_Bases] FOREIGN KEY([ExamBase])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Bases] ([BaseID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Exams]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Exams_Periods] FOREIGN KEY([ExamPeriod])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Periods] ([PeriodID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Exams]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Exams_Users] FOREIGN KEY([ExamUserID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
NOT FOR REPLICATION 
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Exams] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Exams_Users]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Exams]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [UserRanks_Exams_FK1] FOREIGN KEY([ExamUserRank])
REFERENCES [dbo].[UserRanks] ([RankID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Which direction does the foreign key go? Does cat.food reference dog.food, or vv.?

Comment: Can you post the full DDL (including FK definitions) for both tables?

Comment: The DDL you posted works fine for me. When I delete a `Period` it nukes out the corresponding exams. Is that what you were expecting? Also do you get any errors or it just fails silently?

Comment: Running this script in a new 2008 database (and removing the FKs I can't create due to missing tables), deleting from Periods causes matching rows from Exams to be removed. So there must be something else

Comment: Martin, that's exactly what I was expecting. I don't get any errors - the row just gets deleted in the periods and not in the exams.

Comment: Does the NOCHECK option on your foreign key cause this problem?

Comment: did this long ago but must you not append this to the end of the foreignkey column on cascade delete

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've solved the problem.

In the relationship window, there was an option called `Enforce Foreign Key Constraint`, which was set to "No".
I set it to "Yes" and now row deletion works well.

Answer (score 4):

Can you show your table structure more concretely?
It sound like you have the PK/FK the wrong way around.

Deleting the FK part (child) does not do anything to the PK record (parent).
Only when you delete the PK records does it cascade to the child records that link to it.

Comment: Dog.food is the primary key, cat.food is the foreign.

Comment: The row I delete is from the dog table.
how do I get the table structure in a code form?

Comment: @jbkkd - You can right click on the tables in SSMS and script the tables 'AS CREATE' to the window - post those scripts.

Answer (score 3):

**For people using SQL Server Management Studio:**

I've absolutely seen cases where the UI has got out of sync with the DB, even if it you refreshed the keys list or opened a completely new instance.

For my case I have an `Order` which has `DiscountedItem` child items.

The way to check if things are out of sync is to right click on `FK_DiscountedItem_Order` and select `Script Key as CREATE To Clipboard` and then examine what you get :

You *should* get something like this :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DiscountedItem]
WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_DiscountedItem_Order] FOREIGN KEY([OrderId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Order] ([OrderId])
ON DELETE CASCADE; --should be seeing this!

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DiscountedItem]
CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DiscountedItem_Order];
```

Where you can clearly see `DELETE CASCADE`.

If you get something like the following, then the cascade rule **isn't** actually active despite what the UI may say :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DiscountedItem]
WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_DiscountedItem_Order] FOREIGN KEY([OrderId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Order] ([OrderId]);
```

I just deleted it (had to actually delete it twice) and recreated it to get the correct SQL.

You may need to run something like this to check for 'orphaned' child rows :

```
select * from DiscountedItem
where DiscountedItem.orderid not in (select orderid from [order])
```

And then if it is safe to do so :

```
delete from DiscountedItem
where DiscountedItem.orderid not in (select orderid from [order])
```

---

Why did this happen?

I *just* added the constraint and immediately got a foreign key error because I had orphaned rows. Something then got confused and it thought cascade was enabled.

So before creating a new constraint in the UI I recommend you always check first for orphaned rows. You will have to delete them anyway if they exist.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the column `food` in `dog` is the primary key of `dog`? If you have a table called `food`, then it's column `food` should be the primary key of `food` and a foreign key of `dog` (and `cat` as well). Then with `on delete cascade` deletions on `food` will cause the corresponding rows on `dog` and `cat` to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If the cat table is the key for the foreign key, then deleting a row from dog will not delete a row from cat, rather it would work the other way around.

Comment: why would it work the other way around? cat row depends on the dog row.

Comment: @jbkkd - if you read the answer, it starts with an if.  Your example was a little unclear, but the DDL and your comment clears it up.  Are you sure that there are no triggers on your tables that are causing problems.  Are you sure that the foreign keys are enabled?

Comment: Positive. I deleted a row in exams table and it was deleted from the relveant rows in examquestion for example, which is the table with the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

This seams to work just fine.

```
delete from Periods where PeriodID = 1
```

will delete one row from Periods and all rows from Exams that have ExamPeriod = 1

Comment: that's exactly my problem, it doesn't work. anything else I need to check that I missed?